# Calculate subsets of a given list of integers

Tags: python, list, recursion

```
class Solution:
    def subsets(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        res = []
        subset = []
        
        def dfs(i):
            if i >= len(nums):
                res.append(subset.copy())
                # print(res)
                print(subset)
                return
            
            subset.append(nums[i])
            dfs(i+1)
            print("hi")
         
            subset.pop()
            dfs(i+1)
            print('hello')
            
        dfs(0)
        return res
```

This code is for finding subsets of a given list of integers, and it is working fine. But I am not able to trace code that how it is working, so I added `print(subset)`, `print('hi')` and `print('hello')` but though I am not able to understand.
input: `[1,2]`
output :

```
[1, 2]
hi
[1]
hello
hi
[2]
hi
[]
hello
hello
```

I am able to understand only first 4 lines of output( when i become 2 it is printing `[1,2]` then `hi` then 2 is popped and return `[1]` then `hello`.). What I am thinking is if it is printing `hello` means function call is done, then why it is working for rest of subsets (`hi`, `2`, `hi`, `[]`, `hello` `hello`)?

Hope, I am able to explain my doubt!
**Thanks :)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand, but "hello" here DOES mean a function call is done, as it is the last thing printed in some cases when the function is called.
Specifically when `dfs` is called with `i` less than `len(nums)` the function will print "hello" at the end.

But notice how inside the `dfs` function, in that case it calls `dfs(i+1)` twice. This makes it a **recursive** function - a function which calls itself.

This can get complicated to think about - but `dfs(0)` calls `dfs(1)` twice, and each of the `dfs(1)` calls call `dfs(2)` twice. 2 is the length of the list, so it's the base case that stops the recursion by returning from the inner if block (instead of going through the outer dfs calls which end in "hello").
Thus we should see 1 hello after the first `dfs(1)` finishes, then 1 hello after the second `dfs(1)` finishes - and once each of the `dfs(1)`'s return, dfs(0) can finally return and print its own "hello" - for a total of 3 "hello"s. Which is exactly what we see.

Comment: Thanks. But still I am not able to trace recursive function. I can trace if a function calls itself once, but  I get stuck whenever a function calls itself twice.

Comment: I got it.. Thanks a lot